# Distinctness of products of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose that $S$ and $T$ are sets of Fibonacci numbers greater than $1$.  Let $S^*$ be the product of numbers in $S$, and likewise for $T^*$.   If $S^*=T^*$, must $S=T$?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

(**Finite** sets, of course, if you don't want to allow $S^* = T^* = \infty$)

Yes.  We may assume wlog $S$ and $T$ are disjoint, and $\max S < \max T$.  By [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael's_theorem), every Fibonacci number except $1$, $8$ and $144$ has a prime factor that does not divide any earlier Fibonacci number.  So $\max T$ can only be $8$ or $144$, and neither of these work.